Hacer múltiples registros solicitud POST API con PHP y consumida desde C#
No sé como enviar un JSON con un arreglo de objetos ejemplo:
[
{
"ID_licencia": "valorID",
"tipo": "valorTipo"
},
{
"ID_licencia": "valorID",
"tipo": "valorTipo"
}
]
por medio de solicitud POST a una API en php. Puedo hacer registros individuales o varios pero usando un for desde C#, el motivo de porque busco la alternativa de mandar el arreglo es que haciéndolo con el for en ocasiones no se registra todo, por ejemplo pongo una iteración de 50 registros, a veces hace 48,47 o los 50 y además creo que no es practico porque se están haciendo muchas llamadas a la API y no sé si el hosting lo vaya a permitir
aquí pongo el código en C# donde llamo la API:
public async Task Post_Licencia(LicenciaCE[] objLicencias)
        {
            var url = $"miapi.php";
            var cliente = new HttpClient();

            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objLicencias, Formatting.Indented);
            HttpContent content = new StringContent(json, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            var httpResponse = await cliente.PostAsync(url, content);

            if(httpResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
                var result = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                MessageBox.Show(result);
                MessageBox.Show(json);
            }
        }

Código en PHP de la API para el registro:
function insertar($conexion){
    $dato=json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'),true);
    $ID_licencia=$dato['ID_licencia'];
    $tipo=$dato['tipo'];
    $fecha_compra=$dato['fecha_compra'];
    $fecha_activacion=$dato['fecha_activacion'];

    $sql="INSERT INTO licencias(ID_licencia,tipo,fecha_compra,fecha_activacion) VALUES('$ID_licencia','$tipo','$fecha_compra','$fecha_activacion')";
    $conexion->query($sql);
}

Este es el error que me aparece al querer mandar el arreglo de objetos:

Creo que debo corregir el código en PHP porque no puede recibir arreglos, solo que tampoco sé si sea eso posible, llevo algo de tiempo buscando la solución y estoy pensando si dejarlo con los registros con el for y poner un limite de por ejemplo 5 registros, aunque realmente igual a veces se hacen los 5 otras veces 4, aquí el código usando el ciclo for, si me ayudan con la solución de alguna de estas dos maneras yo estaré muy agradecido.
 public async void licenciasCE(int cantidad, string tipo)
        {
            //LicenciaCE[] licencias = new LicenciaCE[cantidad]; ESTO ES PARA MANDAR EL ARREGLO DEL EJEMPLO ANTERIOR
            var fecha_compra = "2024-04-29";
            var fecha_activacion = "2024-04-29";

            for (int i = 0;i<cantidad;i++)
            {
                objLicencia.ID_licencia = Generar_Licencia();
                objLicencia.tipo= tipo;
                objLicencia.fecha_compra = fecha_compra;
                objLicencia.fecha_activacion = fecha_activacion;
                //licencias[i] = objLicencia; ESTO ES PARA MANDAR EL ARREGLO DEL EJEMPLO ANTERIOR
                await Post_Licencia(objLicencia);
            }

            //await Post_Licencia(licencias); ESTO ES PARA MANDAR EL ARREGLO DEL EJEMPLO ANTERIOR

        }

Muchas gracias por la ayuda.
ACTUALIZACION:
Modificando el código en php con la ayuda de @Yussef sigo recibiendo el mismo error, aquí lo pruebo directamente por si es que el problema sea en el llamado en C#, pero igualmente recibo el mismo error

Adjunto igual como tengo el header

Gracias de nuevo por la ayuda.

En efecto, tu PHP no está preparado para recibir una lista de datos. Según tu código, deberías hacer algo como esto

function insertar($conexion){
    $datos=json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
    $values = [];
  
    foreach($datos as $dato){
      $values[] = "('$dato->ID_licencia','$dato->tipo')";
    }

    $sql="INSERT INTO licencias(ID_licencia,tipo,fecha_compra,fecha_activacion) VALUES".join(",",$values);

    $conexion->query($sql);
}

Nota: Estas realizando operaciones a la base de datos de forma insegura, recomiendo leer ¿Por qué no se debe usar la API mysql_* en PHP/MySQL?, sobre todo si tu API la utilizarán terceras personas

Hola, muchas gracias, por tu comentario, disculpa la verdad es la primera vez usando APIS y estoy batallando con esto querer insertar varios registros, todas las demás solicitudes funcionan, solo quisiera esta funcionalidad de varios registros, pero se me esta complicando, edité la pregunta para que veas que más podría ser. Muchas gracias.

@José Prueba quitar el true en file_get_contents, que quede así $datos=json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));

@Yuseef Por favor me podrías pasar la documentación de tu solución, la verdad estoy encantado, me gustaría aprender más y ver si puedo aplicarlos para solicitudes PUT o DELETE, desde el primer día le di a tu respuesta flechita arriba, pero me marcaba que espere a dos días algo, pero tu respuesta es increíble, elegante sencilla jejeje. Muchas gracias de nuevo.

SOLUCIÓN
Cambié el código en PHP de la siguiente forma

function insertar($conexion)
{
    $datos = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
    foreach ($datos as $row) {
        $ID_licencia = $row['ID_licencia'];
        $tipo = $row['tipo'];
        $fecha_compra = $row['fecha_compra'];
        $fecha_activacion = $row['fecha_activacion'];
        $sql = "INSERT INTO licencias(ID_licencia,tipo,fecha_compra,fecha_activacion) VALUES('$ID_licencia','$tipo','$fecha_compra','$fecha_activacion')";
        $conexion->query($sql);
    }
}

SOLUCIÓN MAS LIMPIA POR @YUSEEF
function insertar($conexion)
{
    $datos = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
    $valor=[];
    foreach ($datos as $row) {
        $valor[]="('$row->ID_licencia','$row->tipo','$row->fecha_compra','$row->fecha_activacion')";
    }    
    $sql="INSERT INTO licencias(ID_licencia,tipo,fecha_compra,fecha_activacion) VALUES".join(",",$valor);
    $conexion->query($sql);
}

Gracias a @Yussef por responder y la guía.
Hasta luego.

Que bueno lo hayas solucionado, esto se debe a que el true de la función file_get_contents convierte el objeto a un array asociativo. Por otro lado, favor editar tu respuesta y en lugar de colocar una imagen, coloca el código como texto

Listo, intenté poner en un principio el código pero salían advertencia del formato que supuesta está mal, esta vez los ignore y para que se ve bien jejeje. Gracias de nuevo.

Que bien, un último comentario: De la forma que lo estás haciendo, estas realizando un insert por cada registro. Fíjate en mi respuesta, yo hago un solo insert para todos los registros que es más eficiente. Por eso lo guardo en un array y al final con un join junto tondo en una sola sentencia

Hola, Gracias Yussef, si me gustó mucho tu solución, pero no al principio no pude adaptarlo, hasta estos momentos que ya funcionó. Muchas gracias.
